# error opening a port in Google Compute Engine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I am trying to open a port via ssh in my VM instance in Google Compute engine but I keep getting error messages.

Here is my command:

```
myname@instance-2:~$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create baasbox-console-port --allow tcp:9000 --source-range
s=0.0.0.0/0
```

here is the error message:

```
NAME NETWORK SRC_RANGES RULES SRC_TAGS TARGET_TAGS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.create) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Insufficient Permission
```

pls what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`gcloud auth login`
Go to the following link in your browser:
(Cut and past the link into your browser address bar)
For me (Ubuntu 14.04) this does not return a verification code on FireFox, use Chromium. You should get a long string of characters as a verification code. Cut and past this into the terminal. I would then see this:

ERROR: There was a problem with web authentication.ERROR: (gcloud.auth.login) invalid_grant

After several tries of generating the code and pasting it, I copied the code and the trailing colon(:) then it worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to do either of the following:

1. run `gcloud auth login` in your instance, or
2. when you create your VM, you need to give it read-write access to Google Cloud Platform APIs by adding the `compute-rw` scope as follows:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances create $VM --scopes compute-rw [...]
   ```

   See the [`gcloud compute instances create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) docs for more info.