# gcloud compute list networks error: "Some requests did not succeed: - Insufficient Permission"

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have created a project and setup a Windows 2012 VM. I am trying to list the networks in the project. Here are the steps I performed:

Initially, I logged into the VM as per the credentials created when creating the VM.
From there, opened the Google Cloud SDK Shell (As Administrator) 
Next, I set the project name as follows:

```
C:\windows\system32> gcloud config set project <proj-name>
```

Then, I tried to list the networks (should only be one - default). Here is the error relating to permission.

```
C:\windows\system32> gcloud compute networks list
NAME IPV4_RANGE GATEWAY_IPV4
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.networks.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Insufficient Permission
```

Answer (score 21):

This is a problem with the permissions of the credentials of the created Virtual Machine.

To work around, you can use `gcloud auth login` and log into your Google account via the browser. You may also create a service account in the Cloud Console and load it onto the machine, then activate using `gcloud auth activate-service-account`.

---

This issue is easiest to see in the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.sdk.google.com/). Navigate to the instance page for this VM; you'll see something like:

[image: Permissions for VM, showing "Compute" set to "Disabled"]

Note that "Compute" is set to "Disabled".

To change these permissions when creating a new VM instance in the Cloud Console, expand the "Management, disk, networking, access & security options" view:

[image: Management, disk, networking, access & security options]

Then, navigate to "Access & security" and change the permissions for "Compute":

[image: Set Permissions]

This will create the new Virtual Machine that has read access to your project's Google Compute Engine settings.

---

To create a new instance using `gcloud`, add the following  flag to `gcloud compute instances create`:

```
--scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute.readonly"
```

You'll need to add any additional permissions you'd like, as well.

Comment: Looks like we'll able to change this on a running instance soon too - https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/13101552-ability-to-change-cloud-api-access-scopes-on-launc?page=1&per_page=20

Comment: Now we *can* change an instance (in console click on the instance and use `EDIT` button above). We have to change `Cloud API access scopes`. For example you may set it to `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs`.

Answer (score 8):

First use [`gcloud auth login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) command to authenticate and get credentials for the tool.

Answer (score 1):

As Misha Brukman in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596998/error-opening-a-port-in-google-compute-engine) answered, you don't have to include the url (as this might change) but simply can type the --scopes option "compute -rw" as in:

```
gcloud compute instances create <vm name> --scopes compute-rw
```

If you have already created your vm instance, you can simply use the equivalent update command like this:

```
gcloud compute instances update <vm name> --scopes compute-rw
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same error when i was trying to execute "gcloud compute zones list" command (When I logged into GCP instance by using "Open in browser window" option).

[image]

Below are the steps which I executed to get it resolved.

Step 1 : Log into GCP instance using "View gcloud command option".

[image]

Step 2 : Click on "Run in Cloud Shell command"

[image]

Step 3 : Execute gcloud specific command . In my case it was "gcloud compute zones list". 
[image]

Hola!! It works like magic.!!