# Getting Error "- Insufficient Permission" while creating a ssl-certificate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authorization, ssl-certificate

I have .crt, .csr and .key file in ssl_cert directory of my gcloud VM. While creating a SSL Certificate I am using following command -

> gcloud compute ssl-certificates create SSL_CERTIFICATE --certificate
>   /home/USER/ssl_cert/ssl.crt --private-key /home/USER/ssl_cert/ssl.key

and after executing the above command I get below error -

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssl-certificates.create) Some requests did not
>   succeed:
>    - Insufficient Permission

Can someone please help in resolving this basic error?

Answer (score 3):

Run this gcloud command on your SSH terminal

```
gcloud auth login
```

A login link will be generated for you in the SSH, click on it, it will require you to login with **the gmail account that owns the project**. A code will be generated for you after login, copy and paste it back in your SSH terminal on the line where you have

```
Enter verification code :
```

Then hit the enter button, permission will be granted.
Try to rerun your initial command that returned insufficient permission.

Comment: I want to use it with a service account. What permission do I need?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be related to this post:

[gcloud compute list networks error: "Some requests did not succeed: - Insufficient Permission"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905966/gcloud-compute-list-networks-error-some-requests-did-not-succeed-insufficie)

The solution suggested in the above post is to run the command: **gcloud auth login**. This will generate an authentication url. Copy and paste this url to your browser. It should return an authentication code. Enter this code in your command shell

Answer (score 0):

"Insufficient permission" is returned by the web interface if you have not yet validated the domain for which you are uploading the certificate. I.e. if you are uploading a certificate for example.com you must have demonstrated that you own example.com.

To to this, using the GCloud web interface navigate to APIs & Services -> Credentials, and then click on Domain Verification. Then Add a domain. This will take you to a set of tools to allow you to validate that you own the domain. (In my case I added a TXT field in the DNS record.)

With this done, you can upload a certificate for that domain.

Answer (score -1):

As per your question, you don't have full access to your server. Please ask your hosting provider to get you the full access for the same.